# What is a "tittering order"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can you help me about the exact meaning of the words in bold?

> In an emotional meeting with some hundred remaining deputies on February 3, deputies reaffirmed their loyalty to the **tittering order**.

Note: Deputies were expressing their loyalties to a regime which was collapsed 8 days later. But, the meaning of "tittering order" is ambiguous for me. *Titter* is nervous laugh but its meaning in this sentence is unclear. I guess it means "ridiculous order" but I am not sure.

Comment: Source: The Shah, the Islamic Revolution and the United States
By Darioush Bayandor, page 379

Comment: Presumably a typo. English comedian [Frankie Howerd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankie_Howerd)'s catchprase was "Titter ye not!"

Answer (score 27):

Given the context of a regime on the verge of collapse, it looks very much like a typo.

I strongly suspect the intended wording was "their loyalty to the **teetering** order."

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*teeter*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teeter):

> **1 a** : to move unsteadily : WOBBLE
>   **1 b** : WAVER, VACILLATE
>   // *teetered* on the brink of bankruptcy
>   **2** : SEESAW

Comment: Thanks very much, It must be the same you said. The Regime was collapsed few days.  It was a serious problem for me. Thanks again.

Comment: ... or just conceivably "tottering" (with very similar meaning).

Comment: @MartinBonner It's appropriate that [*teeter-totter*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teeter-totter) can be synonymous with *seesaw*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for the link — I'd never come across that word before!  Is it common in the USA?  (It certainly isn't in the UK, where I've only ever heard that referred to as _seesaw_.)

Comment: @gidds At least in the playgrounds of New York City, *seesaw* is the only term used for those. *Teetertotter* might be a thing in other regions of the US though; I feel as though I was aware of that usage before Jason mentioned it.

Comment: @gidds I *have* heard the word before. I would actually use it over *seesaw* when it comes to the noun—although I'm used to *seesaw* as a verb.

Comment: @gidds, being British I've only ever heard the term in the Eminem's "Lose Yourself": "Teeter totter caught up between being a father and a prima donna".  This side of the Atlantic, "seesaw" is used as both noun and verb.